# How to check if page are in range (kaminari)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

Is it possible to check if page are in range? Something like this:

```rb
current_page.in?(1..10)
```

Answer (score 1):

`kaminari` has a method called `out_of_range?`. Here are some examples: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#query-basics.

You can do:

```
current_page <= total_pages # assuming you store total_pages somewhere.
# OR
your_model.page(current_page).out_of_range?
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that I did not find a ready-made solution. It turned out to be quite simple to write.

```rb
params[:page].to_i.in?(0..6)
```

Comment: You should not hardcode the interval. I suggest you use what kaminari has built-in.